# Password protect Laravel subfolder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, laravel, directory, password-protection

It seems I can't simply override Laravel's routing when trying to password protect a subfolder in views with htaccess. I put it and an .htpasswd file together in the folder that I wanted to create authentication for but with no effect.
The reason for this is I want to have "client's eyes only" folders for work in progress projects, e.g. "example.com/clients/my-client/". These folders will only contain static content.

I tried adding a folder tree in public but that doesn't seem to work either (I guess public content needs to be declared to avoid being routed?). I'd rather stick with having these client pages as views.
Ideas?
Running Laravel 4.2 on Apache.

Comment: It doesnt work that way at all. If you want to block access, use the Auth class

Comment: It's not possible to override the routing in views? I guess I can use the Auth class but that would require me to hook up a database, right?

Comment: You can use Auth without hooking up to a database, but you'll have to write [your own Auth provider](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#authentication) that will just lookup a file or config array key. Or, if you don't use a database elsewhere in the site (and thus don't want to have to hook up to one), you could use the SQLite database driver, which stores the database in an easily-accessible file.

Comment: @StaffanEstberg no problem - I've written our comments up as an answer if you wanted to accept it for others finding the question.

Comment: Great, thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way Laravel does routing, all URIs are actually virtual URIs, so you can't put `.htaccess` files within any directories, as they're not really there.

However, you can use Laravel's Auth system to protect your routes (either using basic auth or a more traditional login form system).

If you don't want to have to hook Laravel up to a database just to protect some directories there are a couple of solutions:

- You can write [your own Auth provider](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#authentication) that will just lookup the details in a file or config array key. It's not super-difficult to do this, though it may seem a little over the top just for the purposes you have.
- You could use the SQLite database driver, which stores the database in an easily-accessible file (in `app/database/`) so the database is at least kept alongside your code.